# What chemical compound makes colour change to copper into brown like this?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

[image: copper statue finished with chemical compound]

What chemical compound should I use to change the colour to make copper statue like this shown in picture

Comment: $\ce{CuO}\mathstrut$.

Comment: Are you sure it is copper, not bronze?

Comment: See https://www.sciencecompany.com/Patina-Formulas-for-Brass-Bronze-and-Copper.aspx ... information available after cursory online search

Comment: It's copper statue, brushed with soluble chemical. Sodium Phosphate change colour like little bit black, but I need brown in colour as in picture